# xcodebuild cannot find correct iOS Development Certificate under cron

Tags: ios, xcode, cron, certificate, xcodebuild

I am currently using xcodebuild command line tool to build and deploy the app to iPhone as follows.

I saw in my login keychain that the iOS Development Certificate does exist but the key does not match Key1 as shown in the output. My question is how to allow xcodebuild to pick the correct iOS Development Certificate that is currently in the keychain.

**Build Command**

```
HOME=/Users/mcj xcodebuild build-for-testing -project ios/ios_test_app/HXKPIIOS/HXKPIIOS.xcodeproj -scheme HXKPIIOS -destination 'platform=iOS,id=<iPhoneUDID>' -derivedDataPath /opt/HX/HXKPI_Logs/kpi18_iOS_2018-06-23-21-20-01-149882/<iPhoneUDID>/build_derived_data | tee /opt/HX/HXKPI_Logs/kpi18_iOS_2018-06-23-21-20-01-149882/<iPhone UDID>/uitest/build1.log
```

**Output**

```
User defaults from command line:
    IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /opt/HX/HXKPI_Logs/kpi18_iOS_2018-06-23-21-20-01-149882/<iPhoneUDID>/build_derived_data

=== BUILD TARGET HXKPIIOS OF PROJECT HXKPIIOS WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
Code Signing Error: No signing certificate "iOS Development" found:  No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID "<Key1>" with a private key was found.
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Project Navigator >> "General" tab. Look for the "Signing" section and you will see your Team, Provisioning Profile, Signing Certificate, and your Signing Status. Perhaps there is an issue with your Status as you were unable to sign in with your account. In that case, simply press Sign In... and re-enter your credentials. Or, perhaps, you are signed in on a team that does not have your Signing. In that case, go to the Team section and simply change which team you are signed in with. And finally, check your signing certificate in the Signing section. If its empty, that's why Xcode doesn't recognize your certificate.

Comment: Checked my General -> Signing
It says "Automatically manage signing" which is checked and the Team is selected as expected. If you read my question, you can know that the Build command mentioned does work perfectly when I try to run it manually through terminal as it can find the correct certificate under login keychain but it cannot find the correct certificate when it is run under cron. I assume the reason for this might be that login keychain could not be found under cron. I also tried copying-pasting the iOS Development Certificate under System Keychain but the error still persists.