# Flutter export IPA Pipeline in Azure DevOps

Tags: flutter, azure, dart, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have two question

1- If I install multi certificates using `InstallAppleCertificate` task
which value will store on `APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY`. what about `InstallAppleProvisioningProfile` if I use it twice as well.

2- I am trying to export ipa but I'm getting. I read about it most of them say it is sigening issue.

```
##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
```

I install Flutter, certificate, Provisioning Profile then I tried these tasks, but all of them gave me the same error

I tried

- App Store profile with Apple Distribution Certificate
- Ad Hoc profile with iOS Distribution (App Store and Ad Hoc) Certificate
- iOS App Development profile with Apple Development Certificate

  ```
     - task: FlutterBuild@0
       displayName: 'Flutter Build ios'
       inputs:
         target: 'ios'
         projectDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
         buildName: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
         iosCodesign: false

     - task: Xcode@5
       condition: true
       inputs:
         actions: 'archive' 
         sdk: 'iphoneos'
         scheme: 'Runner'
         configuration: 'Release'
         archivePath: '**/build/ios/Runner.xcarchive'
         exportPath: '**/build/ios'
         packageApp: true
         xcWorkspacePath: '**/Runner.xcworkspace' 
         signingOption: 'nosign'

     - task: Xcode@5
       condition: true
       inputs:
         actions: 'archive'
         xcWorkspacePath: '**/Runner.xcworkspace' 
         scheme: 'Runner'
         sdk: 'iphoneos'
         configuration: 'Release'
         packageApp: true
         exportOptions: 'plist'
         exportOptionsPlist: '**/build/ios/exportOptions.plist'
         signingOption: 'manual'
         signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
         provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'

     - task: Xcode@5
       condition: true
       displayName: 'Export ipa'
       inputs:
         actions: 'archive'     
         scheme: 'Runner'
         packageApp: true
         sdk: 'iphoneos'
         configuration: 'release'    
         workingDirectory: 'ios'
         exportOptions: 'auto'
         provisioningProfileUuid: $(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)
         signingOption: 'manual'
         signingIdentity:  $(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)
         archivePath: ios/build/Runner.xcarchive
         exportPath: ios/build
         teamId: 'my team id'
         xcWorkspacePath: ios/Runner.xcworkspace
         args: '-verbose' 


     - task: Bash@3
       condition: true
       inputs:
         targetType: 'inline'
         script: |
           xcodebuild -workspace ios/Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release archive -archivePath build/ios/Runner.xcarchive
           xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath build/ios/Runner.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist ios/exportOptions.plist -exportPath build/ios/App/
  ```

Last task error
`/Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/Runner.xcodeproj: error: No profiles for 'com.myapp.comp' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.myapp.comp'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')`

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)` is default output of the `Install Apple Certificate` task, if you have multiple InstallAppleCertificate tasks, the value could be overwritten by the task which is executed last.

Regarding multiple `InstallAppleProvisioningProfile` tasks, you could encounter errors like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66828140/azure-devops-two-provisioning-profiles-for-ios-app) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53225705/azure-devops-pipelines-xcode-project-with-multiple-provisioning-profiles-fails), you could need to [create plist file with profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54634755/14996050), check signin type.

In addition, as per the error message, you could need to change the signing type to `Project Defaults` or `Automatic signing`.